How does a single layer/single unit with Adam optimizer network work?
I'm very new to ML and I'm trying to mess around with Linear Regression. I tested sklearn's LinearRegression model and then wanted to compare the results to a very simple neural network.
I created a tensorflow Dense network with 1 layer and 1 unit with a 'linear' activation function.
I used 'sgd' and 'adam' optimizers and had the x data scaled using MinMaxScaler
I got very different results (predictions and loss) from the LinearRegression model.
I have two questions:

Is a 1-layer/1-unit network with linear activation the same as LinearRegression?

SGD predictions were quite close, I was testing with house prices, so I would get relatively close results. Target values were in the 1000s, so a $120,000 price was set as 120 in the y_train array. However, when I use Adam optimizer, I get extremely low predictions (less than 20). I started with 100 epochs and increased to a 1000 but still got similar results. Would I be doing something wrong somewhere or does Adam optimizer have limitations or certain requirements for it to work properly.



Try scale your label y using MinMaxScaler too, inconsistent scaling might affect gradient update. Also take a look at how weights are initialized in your tensorflow code and also try adjust learning rate.

well, scaling the target variables (y) made a huge difference (although with a higher epoch). Does this mean that Adam optimizer (and similar ones) require input and target vars to be similarly scaled?

In general momentum-based optimizers such as Adam and RMSProp rely on adaptive estimates of the first and second moments ($m_t,v_t$) of the gradient. Therefore when the scale of the label is large or inconsistent with the input data, the gradients of the loss function w.r.t. the parameters can vary greatly in magnitude, which can cause large updates for some parameters leading to instability and small updates for others slowing down convergence. For example, large gradient increases $v_t$ which can result in smaller updates for its respective parameter even when significant correction is needed. When using Adam, scale both inputs and labels to ensure consistent gradient magnitudes and avoid instability.
On the other hand, SGD without momentum usually has fixed learning rate so that its optimization process won't be impacted much from unscaled disproportionate label values. And tree-based ML models' optimization processes are generally less sensitive to scaling of the label too.

I will answer your first question. Suppose you have observations $(X_{i}, Y_{i})_{i=1}^{n} \in \mathbb{R}^{p} \times \mathbb{R}$. Then the neural network you have in mind can be represented as the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{p} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies
$$
f(x) = W^{(2)}\left(W^{(1)}x + b^{(1)}\right) + b^{(2)}.
$$
Here $W^{(1)}$ is a $1 \times p$ vector and $W^{(2)}$, $b^{(1)}$ and $b^{(2)}$ are scalars (where the $W$ variables represent the usual weight matrices and the $b$ variables are the biases). This would indeed be equivalent to the linear regression function $g: \mathbb{R}^{p}\to \mathbb{R}$
$$
g(x) = x^{T}\beta + \beta_{0}
$$
where $\beta$ is a $p\times 1$ vector and $\beta_{0}$ is a scalar (slope and intercept respectively). Hence if you choose to minimise the squared error loss $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_{i} - \hat{Y}_{i})^{2}$, where $\hat{Y}_{i}$ is the prediction from either linear regression or the neural network, then the two approaches should be identical since linear regression should give you the global optimizer, and you should find the relation
$$
\beta_{0} = W^{(2)}b^{(1)} + b^{(2)}, \quad \beta = W^{(2)}W^{(1)}.
$$
Of course as you can see from here, the neural network parameters are not unique, there are infinitely many combinations that will give rise to the same pair of $\beta_{0}$ and $\beta$. So it is true that any linear function as the function $g$ above can be represented by a neural network with only one hidden unit and one hidden layer, but whether you are able to find the optimal weights depends on the optimisation procedure (I am less knowledgeable about optimisation, so I leave any explanations for why you do not find the same solution to others).
